# Viewing external images in a list (Tkinter in python)

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter

im trying to learn Python and doing some test apps.
Right now im creating a type of image viewer for viewing external images. But have some problems.
I've successfully worked out on how to view the image. But i need to view it as a function, so the image can be updated.

This is what i use for just viewing the image:

```
from io import BytesIO
import urllib
import urllib.request
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


imagelinks = []
***** Here is a crawler that provides image urls from a webpage into the above list ***


root = tk.Tk()

listvalue = 1
url = (imagelinks[listvalue])

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as u:
    raw_data = u.read()
im = Image.open(BytesIO(raw_data))
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
label = tk.Label(image=image)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Everything works well, the image 1 from the list shows up properly.
The problem im having is that i want to add a prev and next button which increment the value of listvalue-=1 and +=1 but simply doing that wont work since it wont update the image in the tkinter window.

Also tried with the Tkinter's update() in my buttons function, but didn't help much either.

Anyone got some input on how to get it to work?

Update:
Tried to put it in a function like this. It is resizing the windows to the proper size, but wont show the image.

```
from io import BytesIO
import urllib
import urllib.request
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()

link='http://img.khelnama.com/sites/default/files/previewimage/features/2013/Aug/IMG-     Reliance_logo(1).jpg'


def showimg(currentimg):
    url = currentimg
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as u:
        raw_data = u.read()
    im = Image.open(BytesIO(raw_data))
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
    label = tk.Label(image=image)
    label.pack()

showimg(link)



root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put your code that retrieves and displays the image in a definition, and pass the list item that it is meant to use as a parameter. That way on a button press, you can increment or decrement the index, and call your own update function you made.

Edit:

Try this then

```
label = tk.Label()
label.pack()

def showimg(currentimg, label):
    url = currentimg
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as u:
        raw_data = u.read()
    im = Image.open(BytesIO(raw_data))
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
    label.config(image = image)

showimg(link, label)
```

Comment: Edited my post and tried this. But wont show my image, just resizing the window.

Comment: @MarkBear34 could you clarify what you mean by you won't get a proper result?

Comment: Sorry, not used to the commenting system here. My post is now updated.

Comment: @MarkBear34 No worries, I have edited my response to better suit your request if I have understood it correctly.

Comment: Can't find a a way to define the image variable in:
label = tk.Label(image=image)

Thanks for helping by the way! ;)

Comment: @MarkBear34 Sorry, edited again. You don't need to assign the image at all the first time.